# Site proposal pages on Area 51 are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, error-message

When I try to visit any site proposal page on Area 51 (e.g. [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language)), I get the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error page.

Area 51's [discussion boards](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) are fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed.

We shut down two private betas yesterday, which I suppose is the cause here? What I can't explain is how or why we ended up with additional site records inserted into the Area 51 DB, which caused there to be multiple rows with matching host addresses that we rely on to be unique.

I'll monitor things for a while to make sure these don't pop back and try to dig up the root cause next week.